# PhpStorm give error when run say Built-in web server is only available since PHP 5.4

Tags: php, phpstorm

My Setup:-

1. Windows Version: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit
2. XAMPP Version: 5.6.3
3. Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
4. PhpStorm 7.1.3

I have been working on Netbeans for quite a long time and recently I ditched it because of its limited features. Setting up a local env using Netbeans is fairly simple and I had no problem with it.

So I installed PhpStorm 7.1.3 thinking it would quite easy to run my PHP web page in the same way when I was using Netbeans, but When I try to run my web page in PhpStorm 7.1.3 using its built-in webserver I get Error:

> Built-in web server is only available since PHP 5.4

What I did is simply import the Project folder (which is in C:/... directory) in PhpStorm and try to run it on browser, but I couldn't get it to work locally. I believe I have to set up Interpreter under settings, but how do I go ahead and what should I include?

When I run my web page using PhpStorm 7.1.3 the Error looks like

[image: This Window is open when I press the Run button]

and after that if I click "Fix" then this window is open

[image: press Fix button]

Took me over half an hour to get this set up!! Should only have been a few minutes, most of it just telling PhpStorm where it was, not guessing WTF it wants. I read all the pages on their website, so sad that.

So, please, can you help me out here

Comment: If you have an old PHP installed before the xampp perhaps its listed in your windows ENV paths.. 
Test in CMD > php -v ..... to verify that it is the 5.6 , because the built in server is service added in php 5.4 and it is not available for older versions..

Comment: 1) You are not using PhpStorm's built-in simple web server (yes, it has one; not sure if your ancient v7 has it though). You are using [PHP's own web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). 2) Just use proper Apache/nginx.etc -- vanilla one or as part of some bundled, e.g. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) / [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) / [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) / [Wnmp](https://www.getwnmp.org/) / [UniformServer](http://www.uniformserver.com/) / etc.

Comment: As for the error: 1) it could be that your PHP installation throws some warnings/error and this prevents IDE from launching PHP's web server. Try launching that server manually in terminal (link is in previous comment). 2) Could be a bug in PhpStorm -- try latest 2016.3.1 version (which is like v13 now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download latest version of XAMPP and install that. It will start working fine after reconfiguration.

Comment: Latest Version XAMPP not supported by that window and jdk

Comment: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html says that you cannot use it with Widows(n missing) XP and 2003. It does not say anything about 7. Also, XAMPP has nothing to do with JDK.

Comment: yes, but Latest Version XAMPP is not compatible with JDK for Netbeans sir

Comment: XAMPP has nothing to do with JDK. That would be your Netbeans problem. But you wanted for PHPStorm. Now I am confused.